# Is there a reason on why its not skipping to the else (Selenium)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
def addtocart():
    #driver.get("https://www.mrporter.com/en-gb/mens/product/nike/shoes/low-top-sneakers/space-hippie-04-recycled-stretch-knit-sneakers/19971654707345242")
    driver.get("https://www.mrporter.com/en-gb/mens/product/nike/shoes/low-top-sneakers/plus-sacai-blazer-low-colour-block-leather-sneakers/10163292708776845?ntfyeu=jo5suw")
    
    while driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div[2]").is_displayed():
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.refresh()
        print("Item out of stock , waiting for product")
    else:    
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div").click()
         

addtocart()
```

In my code if "Sorry, this item is sold out. Add it to your Wish List so you don't miss out if it becomes available again" is displayed on the page I want it to keep refreshing until it becomes instock(the link that is commented has an example of this).When the product is in stock(that message is no longer displayed on the page) I want it to skip to the else.

For some reason its not skipping to the else

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have already witnessed an "in stock" event.

> For some reason its not skipping to the else.

The element you are targeting may still exist at the same [XPath](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), even after its content has changed. Explaining why it keeps being considered as [displayed](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_displayed), i.e. visible to a users.

Anyway, you could try to make things a little more dynamic and less dependent on the structure of the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) by changing your XPath for something more peculiar, say

```
# [...]
while driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'this item is sold out')]").is_displayed():
    # [...]
```

The above XPath performs a [partial text matching](https://devhints.io/xpath#other-things).

Comment: `The element you are targeting may still exist at the same xpath` basically copying what my answer said lol

Comment: "Displayed" means displayed @Jared. Read again what ***you*** have written, and you will see that nobody copied nobody. Moreover (given that questions on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) are supposed to be self-ported), we do not know at that point how things get hidden, really CSS-`display:none;` or else. The OP's words are not to be taken stricto-sensu, and her question is the occasion to improve the approach, while preventing any [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) formulation.

Comment: Any question [@Joshcampbell7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12690016/joshcampbell7) ?