# Element doesn't exist error when trying to get length of dropdown menu using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

```
def addtocart():
driver.get("https://www.mrporter.com/en-gb/mens/product/nike/shoes/low-top-sneakers/space-hippie-04-recycled-stretch-knit-sneakers/19971654707345242")
#driver.get("https://www.mrporter.com/en-gb/mens/product/nike/shoes/low-top-sneakers/plus-sacai-blazer-low-colour-block-leather-sneakers/10163292708776845?ntfyeu=jo5suw")

txt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div[2]").text
while "Sorry, this item is sold out" in txt:
    txt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div[2]").text
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.refresh()
    print("Item out of stock , waiting for product")
else:
    print("The product is in stock!")
    
    #Locates dropdown menu and clicks it
    dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div")
    dropdown.click()

    
    select=Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name("CombinedSelect11__field CombinedSelect11__field--placeholderText CombinedSelect11__field--nativeSelect"))
    print(len(select.options))
```

addtocart()

Im tying to

1. Locate the select class of the drop down menu
   2)get the length of the drop down menu
   3)choose a random number between 0 and the length of the drop down menu
   4)click on the option that matches with that number.

Its saying that the element doesn't exist. I've tried to use the full x-path and class name however both give me the same error.

Comment: Try to consider edits that people take time to do on your (previous) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67962827/4194079). Don't you see that your indentation is incorrect ?

Comment: that was the stackoverflow indentation. I know that the indention on the code above is incorrect and I do consider that people take time with the edits they make

Comment: No it is not the "stackoverflow indentation". Have a look at [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the full xpath, try this selector. It works for me to click and open the dropdown.

```
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.CombinedSelect11')
```

Also instead of

```
select=Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name("CombinedSelect11__field CombinedSelect11__field--placeholderText CombinedSelect11__field--nativeSelect"))
```

try

```
select=Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("CombinedSelect11__field.CombinedSelect11__field--placeholderText.CombinedSelect11__field--nativeSelect"))
```

The class_name function doesn't handle spaces between class names.

Comment: The issue im having is when I try to get the length of "select.options" im getting a no such element " error still even after changing it.Is there a way to get the length/size of the dropdown menu @C.peck